# From continuous distribution to discrete and vice-versa.

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Assume a random variable $a$ that can be either 0 or 1 with probability $\mu(0)=\mu_0$ and $\mu(1)=\mu_1$ respectively (without lost of generality, $\mu_0<\mu_1$). Assume a second variable $X=(a_1, a_2, ..., a_N)$, a vector (e.g. with $N=3$, one realization could be $x=(1, 0, 1)$).

Formally I don't know what I have to assume, but I'm using the probability over X to be

$$P(X) = \prod_{i=1}^N \mu(a_i)$$

Now, consider

$$E(X) \equiv \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \log\mu(a_i)$$

(Maybe this can be defined in a more elegant way, but I think you get the point).

My question is: If I want to define a probability of E, should it it be discrete or a continuous distribution? To be more precise, currently I'm using

$$P(E) = \frac{1}{2^N}\sum_{j=1}^{2^N}P(x_j)\delta(E - E(x_j))$$

where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function, with the normalization

$$\int_{\log \mu_0}^{\log \mu_1}P(E)dE = 1$$

However, I would also agree if someone would use

$$P(E) = \frac{1}{2^N}\sum_{j=1}^{2^N}P(x_j)\delta_{E,E(x_j)}$$

with
$$\sum_{k=1}^N P(E_k) = 1$$

and 
$$E_k = \frac{k\log\mu_0 + (N-k)\log\mu_1}{N}$$

In case both can be used, how can I formally write one as a function of the other?

I'm sorry if this is really bad math notation, I have a Physics background. Please point them out so I can fix (or edit yourself).

Comment: According to your definition of $E(X)$, different states can have the same $E$ right? So the probability you wanna define is on value $E$ or $E(X)$?

Comment: Yes, the same value of E can be obtained for different Xs. I want the probability of E.